# Adding new Mantis status but ran out of enumeration values

Tags: mantis

I was wondering if you had any thoughts about this issue: We want to add one more status at a specific 'place' between two statuses, but we ran out of enumeration for it.

The enumeration looks like this:

```
$s_status_enum_string = "10:new,20:feedback,40:confirmed,50:assigned,52:in progress,53:code review pending,54:merge pending, 56:merged, 58:resolved, 60:testing, 70:tested, 90:closed, 91:updating test documentation";
```

And I want to add a new status between 52 and 53 so that, on the pull-down menu for status, they appear in the desired order.

I tried different things - including changing the .php file definitions then updating the MySQL table's status field in mantis_bug_table, but it messes up all the views and filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The following steps might help you:

1. Redefine the enumeration string as per your requirements
2. Prepare a traceability with your current enumeration values
3. Update the status field in bugs table with the new values
4. Add the enumeration in config.php
5. You may have to reset your previous filters. The filter criteria is stored as a serialized string and it's very difficult to modify.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you happen to know where that serialized string is actually stored?

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a simple PHP script which does the conversion. When this project is over I'll post it here in case anyone needs that kind of thing.

Comment: @Arkandel can you please tell me in detail how you increased the number of statuses ??

Comment: @libregeek can you please explain point number 2,3 and 4 ? I'm having a hard time trying to increase the number of statuses of mantis.. So far I can only change the current ones, but cannot increase the statuses..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having issues with this you need to change the following:

In config_inc.php modify $g_status_enum_string to ennumerate the new statuses as you see fit.

In custom_constants_inc.php make sure to do the same as above.

In the database, run SQL commands such as this:

```
UPDATE mantisclone.mantis_bug_table SET status=100 WHERE status=10;
```

to change the actual records for existing status IDs to new ones.

In custom_strings_inc.php modify $s_status_enum_string and input your new statuses. For example one of mine was:

```
$s_sanity_test_bug_title = "Set Issue Sanity Test";
$s_sanity_test_bug_button = "Issue Sanity Test Pending";
$s_email_notification_title_for_sanity_test = "The following issue is NOW SANITY TEST PENDING";
```

Finally you'll need a small script to change the existing ennumerated values in mantis_filters_table. This was mine, alter it as you see fit:

```
<?php
$mantisDB="myMantisDatabaseName";
mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXX", "YYYY") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mantisDB);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, filter_string FROM $mantisDB.mantis_filters_table");

function parseRecord($statusArray)
{
    $newStatus = array( "10" => "100",
            "20" => "200",
            "50" => "300",
            "52" => "400",
            "53" => "500",
            "54" => "540",
            "56" => "560",
            "58" => "580",
            "60" => "600",
            "70" => "700",
            "75" => "450",
            "90" => "900",
            "91" => "910"
);

foreach ($statusArray as $key=>$value)
{
    if(array_key_exists($value, $newStatus))
        {
            echo "Found value $value, replacing it with " . $newStatus[$value] . "\n";
            $statusArray[$key] = (int)$newStatus[$value];
        }
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$statusID = $row["id"];
$serializedString = $row["filter_string"];
$unserializedArray = unserialize(substr($serializedString,3)); // There's a prepended 'v8#' string in there, don't know why.

parseRecord(&$unserializedArray["hide_status"]);
parseRecord(&$unserializedArray["show_status"]);

$newSerialized = "v8#".serialize($unserializedArray);

// echo $newSerialized;

$changeStatus = mysql_query("UPDATE $mantisDB.mantis_filters_table SET filter_string='$newSerialized' WHERE id=$statusID");
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I hope this works, let me know if you're having any issues.